# XSLT xsl:for-each conditional selection

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of xml that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <tag1>tractor</tag1>
  <tag2>
    <subtag1 att="apple" />
    <subtag2>
      <subsubtag1>red</subsubtag1>        
      <subsubtag2>lunch</subsubtag2>
    </subtag2>
  </tag2>      
  <tag1>forklift</tag1>
  <tag2>
    <subtag1 att="pear" />
    <subtag2>
      <subsubtag1>green</subsubtag1>        
      <subsubtag2>breakfast</subsubtag2>
    </subtag2>
  </tag2>      
  <tag2>
    <subtag1 att="apple" />
    <subtag2>
      <subsubtag1>green</subsubtag1>        
      <subsubtag2>dinner</subsubtag2>
    </subtag2>
  </tag2>   
  <tag1>combine harvester</tag1>
</root>
```

What I need to get transform it so that I get subtags 2 and 3 from each tag2 node, but only the tag2 nodes where subtag1 is apple.  I also need a sequence number for each.

My current code looks something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tag2">
  <apple>
    <seq_num><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></seq_num>
    <colour><xsl:value_of select="subtag2" /></colour>  
    <meal><xsl:value_of select="subtag3" /></meal>  
  </apple>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This would be fine, except that I need the for-each only to return the tag2 which are apples (i.e. subtag1 = apple).  I can't use an xsl:if or an xsl:when because then the sequence number would be inaccurate for the second apple.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rik

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To stay with your code, should be as simple as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tag2[subtag1/@att='apple']">
  <apple>
    <seq_num><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></seq_num>
    <colour><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag1" /></colour>  
    <meal><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag2" /></meal>  
  </apple>
</xsl:for-each>
```

As per the comments below, as suggested, it's better avoid `//`. You should be able when in the correct context. For instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet   version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:for-each select="tag2[subtag1/@att='apple']">
            <apple>
                <seq_num><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></seq_num>
                <colour><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag1" /></colour>  
                <meal><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag2" /></meal>  
            </apple>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apllied on your input, produces the same result. Or still better, avoid the `xsl:for-each` as well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet   version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag2[subtag1/@att='apple']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag2">
        <apple>
            <seq_num><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></seq_num>
            <colour><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag1" /></colour>  
            <meal><xsl:value-of select="subtag2/subsubtag2" /></meal>  
        </apple>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I generally try to avoid the lazy `//` XPath operator - it's a big performance overhead on processing large XML files and can cause strange issues in complex XML documents. If you know the absolute / relative path, use it.

Comment: I have tried your version, unfortunately I made a mistake in my sample code.  The corrected version is now above, but the desired text is not the value fof the tag but oif an attribute of the tag.  Apologies.